# SDK Licenses cannot be found on cordova

Tags: cordova, sdk

Basically I'm using the 27 android API for an cordova APP.
But I get the error that I did not accept the license of the SDK components when trying to debug for device on cordova.

- I accepted the license on android studio SDK manager.
- sdkmanager --licenses on the path for sdkmanager. (using "cd "%ANDROID_HOME%"/tools/bin " and then " sdkmanager --licenses " getting the message "Warning: File C:\Users\ShwSvn.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
  All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates... "

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error :  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.

Does it matter that I have cordova installed on C: and the SDK on D: drive? It shouldn't because it works for example API 24 I guess

Any suggestion?

[image: cordova requirements]

[image: android studio]

[image: licenses]

Comment: Did you install the SDK with Android Studio or did you use the stand alone exe (older) ?

Comment: It was some time ago.. but if I remember correctly it was with Android Studio

Comment: Did you update your SDK recently ?

Comment: No, I did not,
I updated my post with some images to see if it helps in anyway

Comment: Check out the build tools too

Comment: Also have it installed, anyway it's saying "cordova-build error : [Android SDK Platform 27.. " when it's installed and with licenses accepted

Comment: Try to uninstall SDK 26 & 27 and reinstall and accept licences again to see

Comment: I did it, but still the same

Comment: Last thing I can think of is to uninstall and reinstall the SDK but accept the licenses separately (one by one, don't do in bulk)

Comment: Gonna do it now, how do I accept the licenses separately?

Comment: Install one SDK at a time

Comment: @Eric Sorry that I took so long to give information back, but I reinstalled cordova, android studio, everything that I was using (but I have slow internet, so it took a while to install again), installed everything manually again and still have the same error